# Position of the sun in the sky of mars or the moon

Tags: pyephem

I'm interested in designing a device that will track the position of the sun from the surface of the moon or mars.

Is there a way to compute this information within the `pyephem` package, or a way to derive it?

Answer (score 0):

Alas, no — PyEphem can't directly generate positions from bodies other than the Earth. You might want to look at Skyfield, AstroPy, or NOVAS for that possibility.